# Seeding database imlementation of EF6 not working in EntityFrameworkcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

My implementation code for seeding in Entity Framework 6 dosent seem compatible with EntityFramework core

Here is my code

```
public class CustomerOrderSeedData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerOrderEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(CustomerOrderEntities context)
        {

            GetOrderDetails().ForEach(od => context.OrdersDetails.Add(od));

            context.Commit();
        }

 private static List<OrdersDetails> GetOrderDetails()
        {
            return new List<OrdersDetails>
            {
                new OrdersDetails {
                    OrderId = 1,
                    ProductId = 1,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    UnitPrice = 12,
                    Discount = 3

                },
                new OrdersDetails {
                     OrderId = 1,
                    ProductId = 2,
                    Quantity = 3,
                    UnitPrice = 4,
                    Discount = 2
                }
       }
}
```

EntityFrameworkCore doesn't seem to like DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges keyword.Could somebody show me an example of how seeding is done using EntityFrameworkcore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.You cannot use EF 6.X implementation with the EF core.B'cos EF core is having different APIs for that.

You can run the seeding code within a service scope in `Startup.Configure()` as shown below.

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
       var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();       
       context.Database.Migrate();
       context.EnsureSeedData();
 }
```

Here is the link which you can see complete implementation of the above code snippet (see under the **Seeding** section).

[**Implementing Seeding EF Core 1.0**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/)